# Custom units not showing beside leaderboard scores

Tags: android, google-play-games

I'm trying to use Google Play Games Services' leaderboards feature with custom units (in my case the units are "km"), however these units do not show beside the scores when I open my leaderboard on my app. My app is not yet published, if that makes any difference.

Here are my Google Play Developer Console settings:

[image: Google Play Developer Console settings]

Here is what the leaderboard entries look like (I would like it to display 0.43 km as opposed to just 0.43):

[image: Leaderboard entry]

Any help is much appreciated! If you need any more info let me know, thanks!

Edit: I'm launching the leaderboard from my Android app via the following line of code:

```
startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getAllLeaderboardsIntent(getApiClient()), 0);
```

Comment: If you include more information on the response you are getting from the API and how you are accessing it, I can add more detail.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are just getting score instead of getting formatted score. The [Translations and Score Formatting](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards#score_formatting) section of the leaderboard concepts documentation covers using the formatted scores.

You should also check out the [Scores.list response body](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/scores/list) to learn more about the other available formatted / unformatted fields.

Yesterday, I tested the leaderboards with the [Type a Number sample app](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/TypeANumber) and created one leaderboard with a currency format and the other with a decimal format.

Here's the first leaderboard:
[image]

Here's the second leaderboard:
[image]

The boards are being launched using the Android intent as follows:

```
 @Override
 public void onShowLeaderboardsRequested() {
    if (isSignedIn()) {
        startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getAllLeaderboardsIntent(getApiClient()),
                RC_UNUSED);
    } else {
        showAlert(getString(R.string.leaderboards_not_available));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite an old question, but I've just faced this problem.

The official document ([Translations and score formatting](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards#translations_and_score_formatting)) says:

> For Numeric leaderboards, the number format is displayed differently
> per language. (For example, `12,345.78` in the US, and `12 345,78` in
> France.) If you are using custom units and have added translations to
> your game, you must supply translated units for every language you
> have added. **The service then displays these translated units where
> appropriate.**

If I set unit only for `en-US`, no unit shows on my Android device with language setting `ja-JP` for example. Once I change language setting to `en-US`, the unit shows successfully.